# Why would python `__setstate__` accept `None` as a parameter?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I was browsing some of the code from the [serge pygame engine](http://perpetualpyramid.com/drupal/serge) and I cam across something in `serge.serialize` that I couldn't wrap my head around:

```
def __setstate__(self, state=None):
        """Initialize the object to the given state for unpickling"""
        self.initial_properties = Bag()
        #
        # Initialize first from the defaults and then from the live state
        for this_state in (self.__class__._getProperties(), state):
            if this_state:
                for name, value in this_state:
                    setattr(self, name, value)
                    setattr(self.initial_properties, name, value)
```

This method was retrieved from the `Serializable` object. What I'm confused about is why the `state` parameter in `__setstate__` has a default value of `None`. Why wouldn't a state be sent to `__setstate__` upon unpickling an object, and in what situation would this be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't useful if your class relies entirely on `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` for pickling.

As the docs on [`__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) explain:

> Upon unpickling, if the class defines `__setstate__()`, it is called with the unpicked state… If `__getstate__()` returns a false value, the `__setstate__()` method will not be called upon unpicking.

So, if your `__getstate__` returns `None`, it will not be passed back to you at `__setstate__` time; you just won't get called.

However, note that in the [2.x version](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__), this is not true for classic classes. With a classic class, "If a class defines both `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()`, the state object needn’t be a dictionary and these methods can do what they want." (In fact, I believe there are cases where any falsey value turns into `{}`, which isn't very well documented, but the same `if` statement handles that…)

Still, that doesn't explain why you'd need a default value… If you can get `None`, sure, you need to write code that deals with `None`… but you don't need to write code that doesn't get a parameter at all, right?

But, there are reasons you might do this.

First, note that this particular class's `__setstate__` does more than the usual: it initializes "first from the defaults and then from the live state". So, it could very easily be useful to unit test that initializing from the defaults is working.

On top of that, if you define a custom [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) method and unreducer, there's no reason that it has to follow exactly the same rules as the default unreducer. Or course there's no reason it has to call `__setstate__` *at all*—but if you're, say, building a base class that you expect your users to subclass, making your unreducer work as much like the default as possible, so your users can just override `__setstate__` instead of adding their own whole `__reduce__` implementation.

Similarly, if you're building your own serializer on top of `pickle`/`copyreg`, rather than just using it as-is, your code doesn't have to use the exact same rules as `pickle`. Again, there's no reason it has to use even *similar* rules, but doing so might make it much easier for your users to extend your classes.

Whether any of these applies to `serge`, I have no idea, but they're both things that could easily apply to a wide range of types you might want to build.

Comment: @user3002473: Make sure to read the edited version for the bit on classic classes, which I'd forgotten about at first…

Comment: Ahhhh that explains a lot, since if I'm not mistaken the version of serge I was reading off of was built for python 2.x (serge version 0.4.2)